# Notepad ++ Regular Expression on finding missing {/}

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have one big file filled with custom text and scripts, that are used by one software, it crashes because of one problem
The software display whole text throught

{#HEXCOLOR}TEXT TEXT TEXT{/}
for example
{#FF00FF}Hello{/}

as we can see the whole text is inside custom script that starts from {#HEXCOLOR} and ends with {/} but in some lines the "{/}" is missing, that make program crash.

for example
{#FF00FF}Hello

It is possible some how to search for missing {/} in the file via Regular Expression ?

I tried by myself but failed:

{#[^{}]*}.*?{/[^{}]*}

Comment: If this is just for the `{/}`s that may be missing at the ends of lines, okay; but if this is also for the `{/}`s that may be missing in the middles of lines, no regex will help with where the missing `{/}`s should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this pattern

```
({#[^}]+}[^{\r\n]+)(?={#|$)
```

and replace with `\1{/}`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/203)